Looking for a cookbook in a movie/show
I'm sorry but the information provided may be too vague, but I'm really interested in finding this.
There was a show/movie (which had a sort of lifetime'esk feel to it), that featured a character which was destined to write an inspirational book code named The Cookbook. The book had nothing to do with cooking, rather it was a book that in the future would inspire many in a humanitarian effort. But the author would be martyred for his work before it's true impact ever started. 
I saw the movie/show back in 2009, so it likely aired in the mid to late 2000's. The author was African American and was living with his parents. I don't think he was the lead character from what I could tell (but then I could be wrong). 
They found out that his book would inspire people later on in the future from an angel. Not the big wings and feathers kind, just one in street clothes. I think it could have been an angel of death but again uncertain about it.

You are probably looking for Lady in the Water by M. Night Shymalan:

Story is here to find a specific writer whose book will better
  humanity's future. After questioning residents Farber (Bob Balaban),
  Bell (Mary Beth Hurt), Dury (Jeffrey Wright), and five nameless
  smokers, Heep discovers the author, Vick Ran (M. Night Shyamalan), who
  is writing The Cookbook, containing views and ideas so significant
  they will inspire a future President, a great Midwestern orator, to
  greatly change the world for the better. Ran meeting Story eliminates
  his fear and sharpens his inner voice, but he learns he will be
  assassinated due to the controversial nature of his ideas.


You know what that is a possibility. I've seen that movie before but it's not making any connections in my head right now. I'll go back and watch that to see if this is what I'm looking for. Thanks for the input, I'll let you know.

The first paragraph lines up perfectly with the story of the movie.  The author is Indian though, not african american, and lives with his sister.  But yeah, rewatch it, I pretty well guarantee it's what you're thinking of.

forgot to @toombs26

I didn't get to watch it until this last weekend but yes this is the movie! If i knew you in RL I would have to give you a cookie. No really thank you for helping me out it really means a lot.

@Toombs26 no problem.
